# Recognise this thing found in beach?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology

[image][image]

Kindly help me identify this thing found in beach
Chennai, India . Size would be just 1.5 cm in diameter..across maximum size. It's shelled and has something inside it. It make a small noise when it is shaked completely closed on all sides. It's hard surface ( but " fine" texture ) to touch.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Could you explain what you mean by "fine"? It's not quite clear to me what you mean in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find out was this was? We just found one in Florida.

Comment: give us a cross section. describe the material, is it mineral or organic? is it an egg? google lens app will recognize a HD photo if there are other images of the same thing on google images. I just put that specific image through google lens and it returned "chennai, india"...

Answer (score -1):

I believe it’s the seed of a Guilandina bonduc shrub. The seeds are known as nickernuts or sea pearls, and can be found washed up on beaches throughout the tropics. The seeds are often used as counters in the traditional board game manuals.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Biology Stack Exchange and what we do here. Please note there is a section in the help on what makes a [good answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). We particularly value answers here that contain references that support the answer. To improve your answer you could provide links to the shrub and images of the plant and seeds (try wikimedia/wikipedia and iNaturalist) for these in your answer.